How to Import CSV File Columns as Parent/Child Terms to WordPress Taxonomy?
I have CSV file, and 4 columns. The first column has Example 1, the second Example 2, the third Example 3, final column has - codes (numbers). The challenge is, these need to be imported to WordPress Taxonomies:
1-column -> Parent Term
2-column -> Child to the Parent Term
3-column -> Child to the 2-column Parent Term
and each term should have the codes listed on the 4-column in the advanced custom field of each term.
If the row is duplicated, it will be because there was not enough place in the cell for codes (numbers - on the 4-column), and it will be listed on the new row. In this case, codes in the new line should be added to pre-added term's advanced custom field.
The CSV looks approximately like this:
Example 1:  Example 2:  Example 3:
Business    Accounting  Accountancy
Business    Accounting  Accountancy
Business    Business    Administration
Business    Business    Banking
Business    Business    Business Administration
Business    Business    Business and Commerce
Business    Business    Business Computing

And it WordPress Taxonomy, it should like these terms:
 - Business
 - -- Accounting
 - -- -- Accountancy 
 - -- Business
 - -- -- Administration
 - -- -- Banking
 - -- -- Business Administration
 - etc.

P.S. each term should have the numbers on the 4-column!
I tried writing some code for this, but it didn't work out, so, if anyone could help me, I would love it. Thanks.
